# Installing ganib on tomcat

Tags: tomcat

ganib is a project management tool and it's a war file. I have copied it to tomcat webapps folder. I run tomcat via startup.bat and everything is fine and it extracts war file to a folder named ganib. But when I point to localhost:8080/ganib I got error :

HTTP Status 404 - /ganib
type Status report

message /ganib

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

Answer (score 0):

Ganib requires some additional steps in addition to copying the war files.

Steps are as below:

- create database in mysql and import ganib database
- copy/paste database connection and email properties in context.xml
- copy war file and start tomcat.

Please refer to the detailed instructions below: 
http://help.ganib.com/questions/5/ganib-installation-windows

Updated website for open source project management software [http://www.Ganib.com](http://www.ganib.com)
and documentation availble at help.ganib.com/faq/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below things.

- Remove javamelody mapping from ganib/WEB-INF/web.xml if exists.
- Remove if javamelody.jar or jrobin.jar exists in ganib/WEB-INF/lib/
- Need to copy some jars from ganib/tomcat/lib/ to your tomcat's lib
  directory
- Check database settings in context.xml and restart tomcat.

Please provide the exception/error from tomcat/logs/catalina.out.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have followed the instructions given in "[Here](http://help.ganib.com/questions/5/ganib-installation-windows)".

If it still does not work, it may be helpful to run the following tests:

1. Run `{GANLIB_BASE}\tomcat\bin\configtest.bat` from the **command-line**. If you get an message that is related to memory ie; Unable to allocate heap memory for JVM ,  etc.. , you can try step 2.
2. Edit the file : `{GANLIB_BASE}\tomcat\bin\catalina.bat`

**set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=512m**

-Xmx512m : determines the maximum heap size. Play around with this value to find the optimal value.

Comment: Great job, try to make your answer more specific and clean.
@goose